Interpreting a GAM plot for values above and below zero?
I've been going through similar questions on the platform and I feel like there are different perspectives on this. Since I am new to GAMs, I'd like to know how to interpret a GAM plot properly.
What does it mean when the curve moves upward or downward for values above or below zero?
Let's say, my GAM model looks something like this:
model <- gam(y~s(x), method="REML", data=data)


From the plot I can gather that there is an upward trend from values 0 to 500. However, somewhere around 300, the curve goes above zero and keeps rising until 500. Does this mean that as x increases from 0 to 500, y also increases? Or for values under 300, y increases as x increases but the overall effect of x on y is negative?
I've tried looking for answers on different platforms and they've left me even more confused. I'd really appreciate any help right now.

To get a better idea of what this means, compare with (1) a scatter plot of your raw data $y$ and $x$ (2) results from any other smoothing method to check for sensitivity (3) your scientific or other understanding of how the variables could or should be related. Although your curve suggests that $y$ is highest for some intermediate $x$, there are grounds for caution, notably the moderately small number of observations, or at least of distinct values, for high $x$.

I don't know what different perspectives there could be here.

I think we need more detail on your data and your goals to give good answers.  Are there other predictors that you're not showing us? I am not a routine user of R but guess that your syntax shows you smoothing an outcome as a function of one predictor (which is often both interesting and useful).

This question seems to be two lumped into one. Your primary questions seem to be:

What does this partial effects plot actually show?
What does the plot say about my own data?

I answer both below, starting with the first point:
Point 1: I'm guessing based off the formula and the plot that you are plotting a Gaussian curve using the default predicted values. This will naturally give you positive and negative values because this provides you with the partial effect of $x$, which is conditional upon whatever you add into the model. This will usually not look like the original scale of your response variable unless you transform them since this uses the partial residuals, which can often be positive or negative, even if the original scale is strictly non-negative.
Below I simulate data that conceptually looks similar to yours. The code may look convoluted, but all I am doing is estimating piecewise function, adding a positive constant to it (so that the raw values are not negative), and then saving that into an object called data.
#### Sim Data ####
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)
set.seed(123)
x <- seq(0, 3500, length.out = 1000)
y <- numeric(length(x))

#### Define Piecewise Function ####
data <- tibble(x = x) %>%
  mutate(
    ly = case_when(
      x <= 500 ~ 0.01 * x + rnorm(n(), sd = 5),  # Gradual positive association
      x > 500 & x <= 1500 ~ 10 + rnorm(n(), sd = 5),  # No change
      x > 1500 ~ 10 - 0.005 * (x - 1500) + rnorm(n(), sd = 5)  # Gradual decrease
    ),
    y = ly + 10 # add positive constant after piecewise fx
  ) %>% 
  select(-ly) # remove original variable

#### Plot Original Data ####
plot(data)

Which on their raw scale look like this:

We see that the range of values for $x$ match yours and the $y$ values are strictly positive. We can fit the model you specify but also add the residuals to that plot, then resize them to be big enough to see with cex = 2:
#### Fit GAM ####
fit <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = data, method = "REML")

#### Plot Model Alone ####
plot(fit)

#### Plot Model w/ Residuals ####
plot(fit, residuals = T, cex = 2)

The first plot looks similar to yours, though the slopes are a bit more dramatic on both ends (seems my simulation skills are still not amazing, but its good enough I suppose):

The second plot shows us where the residuals are:

Now the y-axis fluctuates around $-20$ and $+20$. The non-residual plot has a different $y$ axis from this one, but that is just because it is showing the constructed regression line's range whereas the residual plot shows the range of the residuals too (which stray pretty far from the regression line here). This is because the partial residuals from a curvy line like this will naturally fluctuate to above the mean residual value ($0$, where the error from a prediction is essentially none) and below or above it (approximately plus or minus $2$, representing large errors) with every fluctuation of the curve. With more terms added to the model, these become partial residuals on the y-axis, which are just residuals from fitting the model after omitting the predictor in question with relation to the others in the model. For a simple case like yours, this would simply look like this since there is only one predictor to omit:
#### Get Residuals from Reduced Model ####
fit.reduce <- gam(y ~ 1, data = data)
ry <- resid(fit.reduce)

#### Plot X Against Partial Residuals ####
plot(data$x, ry)

Which gives us this plot on the same scale as our plot.gam() version:

Point 2: So now that we have established all of that, what does our plot actually mean here? In terms of the pattern from the curve, as $x$ increases from $0$ to $500$, the $y$ also increases, then flatlines, and then curves down, as you noted. So it seems your predictor has an initial positive association with $y$, then ceases to have any association, then has a negative one at the highest values. The plot just shows this in terms of residuals because as you add in more predictors, you have to account for the influence of $x$ independent of the other predictors instead. The positive and negative values just indicate whether or not the residuals are above or below their mean value, but the interpretation is similar to what they would be on their raw scale.

This starts very helpfully but your example seems much more elaborate than what the OP is showing.

@NickCox I'm not sure if I did a better job this time around, but I tried to simulate their data and explain it that way instead.

Indeed. (+1) That well may be closer to what is needed. In general, however, if OPs don't provide good detailed questions, we aren't obliged to guess too much at what they're really asking.
